# How can we tell Grails MongoDB unit test to use a db?

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, grails

I setup a db in MongoDB called spotlight. To connect to that database, I use the following environment setup in DataSource.groovy:

```
grails {
    mongo {
        host = "localhost"
        port = 27017

    }
}


environments {
    development {   // MongoDB instance running without --auth flag.
        grails {
            mongo {
                databaseName = "spotlight"
            }
        }
    }
    test {
        grails {    // MongoDB instance running without --auth flag.
            mongo {
                databaseName = "spotlight"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my unit test class:

```
@TestMixin(MongoDbTestMixin)
class BiographySpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "given a bio then find() returns that bio object"() {

        given:
        mongoDomain([Biography])
        Biography bio = new Biography()

        def nameOf1stImage = "firstImage.png"
        def nameOf2ndImage = "secondImage.png"
        def nameInBio = "star"
        def descriptionOfBio = "a description"
        def id = 0;

        bio.firstImage = nameOf1stImage
        bio.secondImage = nameOf2ndImage
        bio.name = nameInBio
        bio.description = descriptionOfBio
        bio.images = [nameOf1stImage,nameOf2ndImage]

        when:
        bio.save(flush:true);
        id = bio.id

        then:
        Biography bioFromDb =  bio.get(id)
        bioFromDb.firstImage == nameOf1stImage
        bioFromDb.secondImage == nameOf2ndImage
        bioFromDb.name == nameInBio
        bioFromDb.description == descriptionOfBio
    }
}
```

I ran `grails test-app`, and Grails created a biography document in test db, not spotlight db. Is there anything wrong with the way I configure environments setttings in DataSource.groovy ?